# Summarizing values in table

Tags: r

mydata  -> (year-1 to 4 represent sales)

```
 id |year| year_1| year_2 |year_3| year_4
 -----------------------------------
  3 |   1|     22|   10   | 232  | 232
  4 |   2|     22|   23   | 233  | 432
  5 |   3|     40|   23   | 232  | 232
  6 |   1|     22|   29   | 200  | 262
```

Desired output:

(based on year, sales column is obtained, for example id=3 has year=1, so

year_1 = 22    =>   sales=22)

```
id | sales
3  | 22
4  | 23
5  | 232
6  | 22
```

I tried the following code,

```
date_input<- function(table)
{
for(i in nrow(table$id))
 {
ifelse(table$year==1)
  {
  table$sales<-table$year_1
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very intuitive but it will get the job done.

***Data frame***

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(3, 4, 5, 6), year=c(1, 2, 3, 1), year_1=c(22, 22, 40, 22),
                 year_2=c(10, 23, 23, 29), year_3=c(232, 233, 232, 200),
                 year_4=c(232, 432, 232, 262))
```

***code***

```
for(i in 1:dim(mydata)[1]){
  mydata$sales[i] <- mydata[i, mydata[, 2][i]+2]
}

mydata[, c("id", "sales")]
```

Or with the `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries

```
library(tidyr);library(dplyr)

mydata %>% gather(temp, sales, -c(id, year)) %>% 
  separate(temp, into=c("a", "yearnum"), sep="_") %>% 
  filter(year==yearnum) %>% select(id, sales) %>% arrange(id)
```

Comment: I actually removed rows with year=0 but it executes but does'nt create a column named sales   **data frame str** ------------------------------**data.frame': 27542 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ id : num  12 10 11 12 13 ...
 $ year     : num  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
 $ year_2010: num  1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 ...
 $ year_2011: num  1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 ...
 $ year_2012: num  1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 ...
 $ year_2013: num  1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05 1e+05

Comment: Do not post results in the comments. If there is a problem that you are still having, add an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata$sales <- mapply(function(x,y) mydata[,-c(1,2)][x,y], 1:nrow(mydata), mydata$year)
mydata[c('id', 'sales')]
#   id sales
# 1  3    22
# 2  4    23
# 3  5   232
# 4  6    22
```

Comment: even this function creates null values in the sales column

Comment: Something is wrong with your data, @Maddy. Both, the solution of Pierre Lafortune and mine, yield the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this one:

```
sales <- sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(x,y) y[x,y[x,2]+2], y = mydata)
output <- cbind(mydata[,1,drop=F], sales)
#> output
#  id sales
#1  3    22
#2  4    23
#3  5   232
#4  6    22
```

**data:**

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = 3:6, 
 year = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), year_1 = c(22L, 22L, 40L, 22L),
 year_2 = c(10L, 23L, 23L, 29L), year_3 = c(232L, 233L, 232L, 200L),
 year_4 = c(232L, 432L, 232L, 262L)), 
 .Names = c("id", "year", "year_1", "year_2", "year_3", "year_4"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, It just creates null values in sales

Comment: I can't confirm this. Did you use the data that I provided? Maybe your table is stored in a different format. I just double-checked: the code works.

Comment: There is no sense in playing this game. Maddy you presented data and we showed you three solutions. The issue is with your example not our solution.